# Can I search and replace with mathematical expression in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have a following line:

```
set_property LOC DSP48E2_X0Y0 [get_cells{name[0].dut/mm1/dsp_chain[0].dsp_inst}];
```

I want to replace `DSP48E2_X0Y{number}` to `DSP48E2_X0Y{number+5}`
I followed a thread on Stack overflow and I tried to use awk command:

```
echo "set_property LOC DSP48E2_X0Y0   [get_cells {name[0].dut/mm1/dsp_chain[0].dsp_inst}];" | awk `{ printf "%s %s %s_X%dY%d", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5+5}`
```

but I am getting errors:

```
bad math expression: operand expected at `,'
```

Comment: Are you asking about vim or awk?

Comment: Those awk quotes do not look right... you want single quotes, not backticks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question in your title: Yes, just start the replacement with `\=`.

In your case,

```
:s/DSP48E2_X0Y\zs\d\+/\=submatch(0)+5/
```

would do it.

(No idea what all that awk stuff is about.)